# Ipfp function - how to specify the target.list argument

Tags: r

Can someone who understands what the bolded sentence below means please help me understand what it means? It is from R documentation on the Ipfp function. (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mipfp/versions/3.1/topics/Ipfp)

"target.list - A list of dimensions of the marginal target constrains in target.data. **Each component of the list is an array whose cells indicate which dimension the corresponding margin relates to.**

"target.data - A list containing the data of the target marginal tables. Each component of the list is an array storing a margin. The list order must follow the ordering defined in target.list. Note that the cells of the arrays must be non-negative."

As an example, let's say I have this table:

```
seed.ex <- array(1,dim=c(3,4))
seed.ex
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1
```

And these targets stored for the 'target.data':

```
target.row <- c(50,50,100)
target.col <- c(50,50,50,50) 
tgt.data.ex <- list(target.row, target.col)
```

How then should I specify the 'target.list'?

```
tgt.list.ex <- list(?,?)
```

That will then go into the Ipfp fuction...

```
res.ex <- Ipfp(seed.ex, tgt.list.ex, tgt.data.ex, print = TRUE, iter = 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the answer is `list(1,2)`. I've never used this package, but both of the examples that were using two-dimensional seed had that as the answer. Here's my test:

```
tgt.list.ex <- list(1,2)
also installing the dependency ‘cmm’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/cmm_0.8.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 197741 bytes (193 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 193 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/mipfp_3.1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 333155 bytes (325 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 325 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/yq/m3j1jqtj6hq6s5mq_v0jn3s80000gn/T//Rtmp0NHfpB/downloaded_packages
> library(mipfp)
Loading required package: cmm
Loading required package: Rsolnp
Loading required package: numDeriv
> res.ex <- Ipfp(seed.ex, tgt.list.ex, tgt.data.ex, print = TRUE, iter = 1000)
Margins consistency checked!
... ITER 1 
       stoping criterion: 24 
... ITER 2 
       stoping criterion: 0 
Convergence reached after 2 iterations!
> res.ex

Call:
Ipfp(seed = seed.ex, target.list = tgt.list.ex, target.data = tgt.data.ex, 
    print = TRUE, iter = 1000)

Method:  ipfp - convergence:  TRUE 

Estimates:
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 12.5 12.5 12.5 12.5
[2,] 12.5 12.5 12.5 12.5
[3,] 25.0 25.0 25.0 25.0
```